# SubSonic ports for unix use?

Tags: php, unix, subsonic

I'm curious if there are any SubSonic ports for use with php on a unix environment.  I'm using SubSonic at work and I love it, and I'd like to create a MySQL database on a FreeBSD server and talk to it using php.  I was hoping to use SubSonic again, but I'm not sure if there are any versions of it that work with php.

Are there any versions of this out there, or similar products to subsonic that work in php?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any direct ports of SubSonic to Unix. If you're not set on PHP, you could always try .NET running on Mono - that will give you SubSonic as is. [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) is a second option - if I remember correctly, it served as inspiration for many of Subsonic's features.

If you're really set on PHP, you can always try [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/). I've never used it, but I've heard reasonable things about it. [Propel](http://propel.phpdb.org/trac/) is another option. If you're not opposed to full frameworks, I [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), and [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) all have some sort of ActiveRecord implementation.

Comment: I'd love to use Mono, but the reason I'm going to have to use PHP is that my FreeBSD account is a shell account and my admins said that Mono requires a 256 MB virtual machine, which seems pretty steep for one software project.  

CakePHP looks pretty nice, I'll check that one out.  Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

SubSonic is definitly a .Net only project.  I have used SubSonic with Mono to run a blog with a MySql back end on an OpenSuse Linux machine with Apache and found that SubSonic worked well.  If you are stuck on PHP you could just create a webservice with Mono and SubSonic and then call your webservice from PHP or even from JSON if you set your web service up to handle JSON.